# javascript passing the result of a boolean comparison confusion

Tags: javascript, css

I've been working through some text book to learn web development and i've become confused on an example.  The example creates a meter element and fills it with some attributes.  There is then some javascript to check for browser support for the  tag.  The part where i'm confused is after the first expression returns either true or false for the support, shouldn't there be a check for if true or false was returned on the following if statement?  also as an aside, when the create element builds the  element does is give it default values, or grab values from an existing meter in the html.

The check for support is as follows.

```
var noMeterSupport = function(){
    return(document.createElement('meter').max === undefined);
}
```

the next part that builds the meter if the support isn't found is below. This is where i become confused as it seems to take either value and continue without checking if it was true or false.

```
if (noMeterSupport()) {
    var fakeMeter, fill, label, labelText, max, meter, value;
    value = meter.attr("value");
    meter = $("#pledge_goal");
    max = meter.attr("max");
    labelText = "$" + meter.val();

    fakeMeter = $("<div></div>");
    fakeMeter.addClass("meter");
    label = $("<span>" + labelText + "</span>");
    label.addClass("label");

    fill = $("<div></div>");
    fill.addClass("fill");
    fill.css("width",(value / max * 100) + "%");
    fill.append("<div style='clear:both;'><br></div>");
    fakeMeter.append(fill);
    fakeMeter.append(label);
    meter.replaceWith(fakeMeter);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The body of the `if` is only executed if `noMeterSupport()` returns `true`.  The condition in an `if` statement requires something "truthy", i.e. something that can be interpreted as `true` or `false`.  Since the function returns a boolean value, that is sufficient.  (See first Google hit for [truthiness javascript](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/), which is a good explanation.)

**EDIT**: Forgot about your second question.  When a new element is created with `document.createElement`, it does indeed get default values.  In your example, the default value of `max` for a `<meter>` is 1.

Comment: so, noMeterSupport() is only able to return true or nothing?

Comment: No, it can return anything.  The function you have there is guaranteed to return a boolean value (either true or false) since it relies on the triple-equals operator.  (If we want to get extra pedantic, that function is guaranteed to return false, since the "max" property of a <meter> element defaults to 1, which is not undefined.)

Answer (score 0):

`if (noMeterSupport()) {` checks the return value.  It means exactly the same as this:

```
var supported = noMeterSupport();
if(supported) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand your question correctly and will try to answer it.

---

So you would expect something like this:

```
if (noMeterSupport() == true)
```

Actually, this is equivalent to this:

```
if (noMeterSupport())
```

---

And if you want to check false:

```
if (noMeterSupport() == false)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if (!noMeterSupport())
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement will make the function either return true or false:

```
return(document.createElement('meter').max === undefined)
```

basically it would be synonymous with writing:

```
if(document.createElement('meter').max === undefined) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

That makes the value of noMeterSupport() either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
var noMeterSupport = function(){
    return(document.createElement('meter').max === undefined);
}
```

`noMeterSupport` returns the result of the comparison `document.createElement('meter').max === undefined`.

The comparison will be either `true` or `false`, ok?

So, now, when you do

```
if (noMeterSupport()) { /*then do something*/}
```

is like saying

```
if (/*the result of noMeterSupport() is true*/) {/*then do something*/}
```

So, this `if` statement will only run if `noMeterSupport` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
var noMeterSupport = function(){
    return(document.createElement('meter').max === undefined);
}
```

This section of code is not actually doing the check, it is *defining* a function called noMeterSupport.

The code is not actually run until the function is called.  It is called by adding () to the function name.

```
noMeterSupport()
```

Your if() statement is where it is being called as it the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You expect a boolean condition inside the if statement:

```
if(<boolean_condition>)
{
...
}
```

The `noMeterSupport()` is actually returning true or false, so the

```
if(noMeterSupport())
```

is converted to `if(true)` or  `if(false)` 
depending on the result of the `document.createElement('meter').max === undefined` evaluation.

You are receiving a boolean condition and the if statement works fine.

Comment: I get than part, but i dont understand why the if statement doesn't check whether it is passed a true or false.  it's a stupid question i expect but i don't know.

Comment: If you're expecting the `if(noMeterSupport() == true)` just thing about the result of that condition, you will receive `true` or `false` again, and the if statement turns to be `if(true)` or `if(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, there's two points to quickly learn in programming :

1. The comparison operators `==` and `===` not only do the comparison, but returns in fact the result of this comparison (you can place it in var to test)

```
var bool = 1 === 2;
console.log(bool); // will print false
```

2. The test `if(boolean === true)` is equivalent to `if(boolean)`, and the test `if(boolean === false)` is equivalent to `if(!boolean)`